# JQuery function on window events: combine load and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use one if statement. How do I make one if statement?

```
if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
    //mycode
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
        //mycode
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery allows you to assign the event listener to multiple event types.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
        //mycode
    }
})
```

Comment: I was about to press the submit button with this approach! You beat me to it :D

Comment: Gotta be even quicker to find dupes heh?

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be a duplicate. Answering duplicate questions is not such a good idea as it disperses knowledge.

Comment: [The smell](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26534426#26534426).

Comment: [A wise man once said...](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25291870#25291870) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use your existing code, then trigger the `resize()` event afterwards:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
        //mycode
    }
}).resize();
```